# NVelocity messes up my html, or my browser fails to load all scripts?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, castle-monorail, nvelocity

So, i have the following layout (Monorail 2.1, NVelocity View Engine):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>$Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/Site.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/Bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/Bootstrap/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/Bootstrap/bootstrap-image-gallery.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/FileUpload/jquery.fileupload-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Content/FileUpload/load-image.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Content/FileUpload/canvas-to-blob.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Content/FileUpload/tmpl.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Content/Bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Content/Bootstrap/bootstrap-image-gallery.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Content/FileUpload/jquery.fileupload.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Content/FileUpload/jquery.iframe-transport.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Content/FileUpload/jquery.fileupload-ip.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Content/FileUpload/jquery.fileupload-ui.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Content/FileUpload/locale.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Content/FileUpload/main.js">
</head>
<body>
        $childContent

</body>
</html>
```

And the following view:

```
<body>

    <div class="page">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="title">
                <h1>jQuery-File-Upload MVC3 Demo</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="main">
<!-- Shim to make HTML5 elements usable in older Internet Explorer versions -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->

<form id="fileupload" action="/Upload/UploadHandler.ashx" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <!-- The fileupload-buttonbar contains buttons to add/delete files and start/cancel the upload -->
        <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
            <div class="span7">
                <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
                <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                    <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>
                    <span>Add files...</span>
                    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
                </span>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start">
                    <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>
                    <span>Start upload</span>
                </button>
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                    <i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i>
                    <span>Cancel upload</span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete">
                    <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
                    <span>Delete</span>
                </button>
                <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
            </div>
            <div class="span5">
                <!-- The global progress bar -->
                <div class="progress progress-success progress-striped active fade">
                    <div class="bar" style="width:0%;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- The loading indicator is shown during image processing -->
        <div class="fileupload-loading"></div>
        <br>
        <!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download -->
        <table class="table table-striped"><tbody class="files" data-toggle="modal-gallery" data-target="#modal-gallery"></tbody></table>
    </form>

    <!-- modal-gallery is the modal dialog used for the image gallery -->
    <div id="modal-gallery" class="modal modal-gallery hide fade">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
            <h3 class="modal-title"></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body"><div class="modal-image"></div></div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a class="btn btn-primary modal-next">
                <span>Next</span>
                <i class="icon-arrow-right icon-white"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="btn btn-info modal-prev">
                <i class="icon-arrow-left icon-white"></i>
                <span>Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="btn btn-success modal-play modal-slideshow" data-slideshow="5000">
                <i class="icon-play icon-white"></i>
                <span>Slideshow</span>
            </a>
            <a class="btn modal-download" target="_blank">
                <i class="icon-download"></i>
                <span>Download</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
#include("_templates.html")
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Which includes the following html file (_templates.html):

```
<!-- The template to display files available for upload -->
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-upload fade">
        <td class="preview"><span class="fade"></span></td>
        <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
        <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
        {% if (file.error) { %}
            <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">{%=locale.fileupload.error%}</span> {%=locale.fileupload.errors[file.error] || file.error%}</td>
        {% } else if (o.files.valid && !i) { %}
            <td>
                <div class="progress progress-success progress-striped active"><div class="bar" style="width:0%;"></div></div>
            </td>
            <td class="start">{% if (!o.options.autoUpload) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-primary">
                    <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>
                    <span>{%=locale.fileupload.start%}</span>
                </button>
            {% } %}</td>
        {% } else { %}
            <td colspan="2"></td>
        {% } %}
        <td class="cancel">{% if (!i) { %}
            <button class="btn btn-warning">
                <i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i>
                <span>{%=locale.fileupload.cancel%}</span>
            </button>
        {% } %}</td>
    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>
<!-- The template to display files available for download -->
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-download fade">
        {% if (file.error) { %}
            <td></td>
            <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
            <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
            <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">{%=locale.fileupload.error%}</span> {%=locale.fileupload.errors[file.error] || file.error%}</td>
        {% } else { %}
            <td class="preview">{% if (file.thumbnail_url) { %}
                <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" rel="gallery" download="{%=file.name%}"><img src="{%=file.thumbnail_url%}"></a>
            {% } %}</td>
            <td class="name">
                <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" rel="{%=file.thumbnail_url&&'gallery'%}" download="{%=file.name%}">{%=file.name%}</a>
            </td>
            <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
        {% } %}
        <td class="delete">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" data-type="{%=file.delete_type%}" data-url="{%=file.delete_url%}">
                <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
                <span>{%=locale.fileupload.destroy%}</span>
            </button>
            <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1">
        </td>
    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>
```

The problem? When i leave the script and link tags in the head tag, like above, the browser shows me this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>File Upload Tests</title>
<link href="/Content/Site.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/Content/Bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/Content/Bootstrap/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/Content/Bootstrap/bootstrap-image-gallery.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/Content/FileUpload/jquery.fileupload-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript">
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
</head>
<body>
<div id="footer"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What the... ? Where is the rest of my page? Did NVelocity eat it?

BUT if i put the script and link tags at the end of the body tag, it gives me this (the contents of the invoked view are there, but not shown in this post for clarity):

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<body>
<div class="page">
<div id="header">
<div id="main">
<form id="fileupload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="/Upload/UploadHandler.ashx">
<div id="modal-gallery" class="modal modal-gallery hide fade">
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
</div>
<div id="footer"> </div>
</div>
<link href="/Content/Site.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/Content/Bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/Content/Bootstrap/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/Content/Bootstrap/bootstrap-image-gallery.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/Content/FileUpload/jquery.fileupload-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</body>
</html>
```

Where are the rest of script tags?

Comment: Can you post a stand-alone test case?

Comment: I don't have to. My incompetence was at fault. I closed the script tags wrong. NVelocity had nothing to do with the error. Atleast, I found out about #include(..)...

Comment: I just read it again and was about to say the same. :)